# BotUI: Speech bubbles in WhatsApp style

Tags: javascript, css, chatbot

Using [BotUI](https://botui.org/) ([Docs](https://docs.botui.org/)) I'm trying to achieve speech bubbles in WhatsApp style.

[image]

Each first speech bubble has a side tip. So if several messages are written in a row, only the first message has a side tip.

This is what I have so far: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/threeyearold/pen/mdEXVrJ)

**HTML (excerpt):**

```
<div class="botui-app-container" id="hello-world">
  <bot-ui></bot-ui>
</div>
```

**CSS (excerpt):**

```
.botui-message-content:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid #ebebeb;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #ebebeb;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  right: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}

.botui-message-content.human:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid #919292;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #919292;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  right: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

**JS:**

See CodePen.

Comment: What's wrong with your code so far?

Comment: The side tips don't show up correctly.